# R: How to simply count last NA

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to know an easy way, with dplyr,  to count the number of the last NA values for each Id (only if the last value is NA)

```
 my_data <- tibble(Id =c(1,1,1,2,2,2),date = rep(seq.Date(ymd(20210101),ymd(20210103),by =1 ),2), value = c(5, NA, 4, 4, NA, NA))
```

the expected result :

```
 result <- tibble(Id = c(1,2), Result = c(0, 2))
```

I tried

```
 my_data %>% 
     group_by(Id) %>% 
     mutate(test= ifelse(is.na(value), 1, 0)) %>% 
     filter(rle(test)$values[length(rle(test)$lengths)]!=0 ) %>% 
     summarise(result = rle(test)$lengths[length(rle(test)$lengths)])
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**
Many thanks to @tmfmnk who helped me to understand the question and also many thanks to @akrun who again helped me to solve a task! [Count the number only the first occurence of a sequence with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69397717/count-the-number-only-the-first-occurence-of-a-sequence-with-dplyr/69397942#69397942)

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  mutate(value = rev(value)) %>% 
  mutate(first_sequence_A = with(rle(is.na(value)), lengths[values][1])) %>% 
  summarise(lastNAcount = ifelse(is.na(first(value)), first_sequence_A[1],0))
```

output:

```
     Id lastNAcount
  <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1           0
2     2           2
```

**First answer:**
Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  summarise(lastNAcount = sum(is.na(last(value))))
```

```
     Id lastNAcount
* <dbl>       <int>
1     1           0
2     2           1
```

Comment: @tmfmnk, Hmmh you are right. Thanks. I will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
my_data %>%
    group_by(Id) %>%
    summarise(Result = with(rle(is.na(value)), tail(values, 1) * tail(lengths, 1)))

     Id Result
* <dbl>  <int>
1     1      0
2     2      2
```

Answer (score 1):

Grouped by "Id", get the cumulative sum of `rev`erse logical vector and take the `sum` of the 0 values

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>%
  summarise(ind = sum(cumsum(rev(!is.na(value))) == 0))
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     Id   ind
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     0
2     2     2
```

Answer (score 0):

A data table solution (probably not relevant for the OP but might be for someone else):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my_data)
my_data[order(-date), .(Result = ifelse(is.na(value[1]), sum(rleid(value) == 1), 0L)), by = Id]

   Id Result
1:  1      0
2:  2      2
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** this will also do the job

```
my_data <- my_data %>% group_by(Id) %>% mutate(Results = ifelse(is.na(last(value)),with(rle(is.na(value)),1*tail(lengths,1)),0))
> my_data
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   Id [2]
     Id date       value Results
  <dbl> <date>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1 2021-01-01     5       0
2     1 2021-01-02    NA       0
3     1 2021-01-03     4       0
4     2 2021-01-01     4       2
5     2 2021-01-02    NA       2
6     2 2021-01-03    NA       2
```

**First answer:** I am not sure I get your question totally right, because I would expect the result to be `Result=c(0,1)` if,in my understanding, you want the information about the number of NA as last value for each ID. Which could only be 0 or 1 in my understanding. Otherwise, if you want all the NA per Id, the expected result would be `Result=c(1,2)`. I cannot figure out which one would provide `Result=c(0,2)`

So there is this `dplyr` option, that counts the number of NA per id:

```
my_data <- my_data %>% group_by(Id) %>% mutate(Results=cumsum(is.na(value)))
my_data
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   Id [2]
     Id date       value Results
  <dbl> <date>     <dbl>   <int>
1     1 2021-01-01     5       0
2     1 2021-01-02    NA       1
3     1 2021-01-03     4       1
4     2 2021-01-01     4       0
5     2 2021-01-02    NA       1
6     2 2021-01-03    NA       2
```

If you only want the information on the last value :

```
my_data <- my_data %>% group_by(Id) %>% slice(n()) %>% mutate(Results=cumsum(is.na(value)))
    my_data
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   Id [2]
     Id date       value Results
  <dbl> <date>     <dbl>   <int>
1     1 2021-01-03     4       0
2     2 2021-01-03    NA       1
```

If you need `Result=c(0,2)`, please clarify what you need and I will update my post.

Comment: Thanks, for Id ==1 the last value by date is not NA so I want 0, for Id ==2 the last value is NA and I want to count from this last date  to the first value!=NA the number of days which is 2 in my exemple. Sorry if its not clear

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `slice_tail`:

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  slice_tail() %>%
  summarise(n = +is.na(value))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     Id     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     0
2     2     1
```