# Count the number only the first occurence of a sequence with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am struggling with this task:
I have this dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "C", "A"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

  col1
1    A
2    A
3    A
4    B
5    A
6    A
7    C
8    A
```

I want to get the count of `A` in the first sequence only.

**The expected answer is 3!**

**Update: expected not working Output:**

```
df %>% 
  summarise(first_sequence_A = sum(col1=="A")) 
# not working because counting all A's

# resluting in:
  first_sequence_A
1                6

expected:
  first_sequence_A
1                3
```

**I prefer a solution with `dplyr`**

I have tried `cumsum`, `rle`, `lag`... but I can't get it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rle` from `base R`

```
with(rle(df$col1 == "A"), lengths[values][1])
[1] 3
```

---

Or in `dplyr` syntax

```
df %>% 
   summarise(first_sequence_A = with(rle(col1 == "A"), lengths[values][1]))
  first_sequence_A
1                3
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your ideal final output would look like, but maybe something like this?

Edit: probably a better and more succinct way to do this, but...

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df %>% 
  mutate(x = rleid(col1)) %>% 
  group_by(col1, x) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  filter(col1 == "A") %>% 
  summarize(first_sequence_A = n)
```

Gives us:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  col1  first_sequence_A
  <chr>            <int>
1 A                    3
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have updated with the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Using `rleid` from `data.table` -

```
library(data.table)

sum(rleid(df$col1) == 1)
#[1] 3
```

If you want to use it in `dplyr` pipe -

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% summarise(result = sum(rleid(col1) == 1))

#  result
#1      3
```